# Sending directly from a WAV file to a DirectShow Sound Card

Tags: .net, vb.net, naudio

I am using VB.net to integrate sending a wave file to a specific speaker (exactly what is done in the sample file). But, I am having trouble decoding what is actually done in the sample file because what I am looking for is much more simple.

What is the code to send a WAV file to a speaker how do I open and decode said wave file?

Comment: Do you mean that you need to accomplish this task without the use of nAudio?

Comment: No we do not mind using nAudio I just need some help on what functions I need to call to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out simpler then I originally thought.  Figured I would provide my own answer to help someone else looking for the same information!

```
Imports NAudio
```

Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim wavefile As New NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader("C:\Users\iqm2admin\Desktop\Pause.mp3") 'The Audio MP3 file you want to play
    Dim waveout As New NAudio.Wave.WaveOut() 'Create Wave Object
    Dim devicecount As Integer = NAudio.Wave.WaveOut.DeviceCount() 'Count the devices
    Dim TestString As String = "Speaker description" 'The desciption of the speaker you want to play to
    Dim SDevice As String = Nothing
    Dim DeviceNum As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To devicecount - 1
        SDevice = NAudio.Wave.WaveOut.GetCapabilities(i).ProductName
        If TestString.ToLower = SDevice.ToLower Then                   'Find the speaker you want to play to
            DeviceNum = i
        End If
    Next
    waveout.DeviceNumber = DeviceNum ' set the device to play to
    waveout.Init(wavefile)
    waveout.Play() 'play the file
End Sub
```

End Class